# Why is AWS RDS' maximum auto_explain.log_min_duration parameter 214783?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, postgresql-9.6, explain

That seems like a really arbitrary number of [milliseconds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auto-explain.html) to use as a maximum.  What can I do if I want to log even longer-running queries on a data warehouse?

C.f. https://collabshot.com/show/83dd1e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not specific to AWS RDS (well part of it specific to that), it is in the upstream code.

The setting is restricted to `INT_MAX / 1000`.  But I can't figure out why, as that setting is never multiplied by anything, much less 1000.  This seems like a bug to me.  You might want to report it to the PostgreSQL [bugs mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bug-reporting.html).

In the meantime, I guess your option would be to set it to the max and then filter your log files.  It seems unlikely to have millions of queries each taking 40 minutes, so filtering it shouldn't be too onerous.

### update

And soon after your report, it has been fixed in `PostgreSQL` for all supported versions.  It will be included in the next bugfix release, which is due out soon.  I don't know when Amazon is likely to both roll out the next bugfix release to RDS, and fix their own independent bug on the same subject matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Actually, I'm not the one missing the digit--see the screenshot, it's like that in the range that AWS reports (and coming from PostgreSQL directly, it sounds like).  Thanks again, I'll follow up with them.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like PostgreSQL may have a bug, but AWS also has one (typo, perhaps?  The digit it's missing is 3rd from the right-hand side...)  E.g. if I try to set it to 2000000, which is below the number you specified, I get `Error saving: Value: 2000000 is outside of range: -1-214783 for parameter: auto_explain.log_min_duration (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: ...)`

Comment: Just a follow-up, the answer from pg-bugs was that some unknown time buffer is needed.

Comment: AWS staff also responded and said they would be fixing it, but without a timeline.